# background-image: fixed overstretching image

Tags: css, background-image

On my portfolio, I am trying to implement a full-width fixed (not scrolling, not parallax...fixed) background image. This image will serve as the background for a foreground image.

HTML:

```
<header>
    <img src="assets/img/blahblah1.png">
</header>
```

(header has the background image applied and img is the foreground image)

CSS:

```
header {
   background-image: url(../assets/img/blahblah2.jpg);
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-position: 0 0;
   min-height: 15.625em;
   padding: 4em 0 12em;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width: 100%;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -ms-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   padding: 0;
}
```

However, the problem is that `background-attachment: fixed` stretches the image much more than the default.

Please see these two screenshots:  and one without.

[Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/03uoj4z537ein3g/Screen%20Shot%202014-10-19%20at%2010.09.19%20PM.png?dl=0) with `background-attachment: fixed`

[Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ydmtdyerda5v9fx/Screen%20Shot%202014-10-19%20at%2010.21.02%20PM.png?dl=0) with default background-image

What am I missing? Is there a workaround? I definitely want the background image to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with background properties, I think I have found an ideal combination.

- Use `background-size: 100%` instead of `cover` - This will stretch the image in proportion with the container *width*
- Use appropriate max-width / max-height

`background-attachment: fixed` shouldn't have to do anything, but it can be applied.

### Example

Background image - 1000 x 540

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-1000-540-9.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px; /* image width */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 20px;
}
img {
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 50%;
  display: block;
  /* remove inline gap */
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  header {
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: scroll;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-500-500-1.jpg">
</header>
```

Comment: This is a good solution in that it solves the stretching problem. However it creates another problem in that, by no longer using `background-size: contain;` the image no longer covers the vertical width of the div and thus when you size your browser down to mobile widths, you'll see white space.

http://codepen.io/leormaizel/pen/lsuKd

Any input on this?

Comment: Sure, using `@media` have a look at [this example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CbGgn). When the viewport gets too small, switch `background-size` to `cover` and background-attachment to `scroll`. Here I have also set a `max-width` on the body and the **img resizes** with max-width and height.